Boto3 delete ebs snapshots script ...error for parameter snapshotId is invalid. Expected: 'snap-...'
My script is trying to delete ebs snapshots, but I've gotten stuck at this point due to this error. I am not sure what the solution is.
import boto3 
import pprint
from openpyxl import load_workbook
AWS_REGION = "ap-southeast-2"
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name = AWS_REGION)

wb = load_workbook("workbook-1.xlsx")  
ws = wb['Sheet1']
column = ws['D'][0:3089]   
column_list = [column[x].value for x in range(len(column))]  

snapshot_string =" ".join(map(str,column_list)).split(",")
pprint.pprint(snapshot_string) 

for snap in snapshot_string:
    print(f"Snapshot {snap} are deleting")
    ec2.delete_snapshot(SnapshotId=snap) 
    print(f"Snapshot {snap} have been deleted")

the last print statement starts with
Snapshot Snapshot Id snap-0f51c7d3288247f6b 


Ends with
snap-03e488d013824c092 snap-05e6f9163bc26a4b4 are deleting


The error is
snap-03e488d013824c092 snap-05e6f9163bc26a4b4)
for parameter snapshotId is invalid. Expected: 'snap-...'.



@jarmod  for snap in snapshot_string.split():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

What does the print(f"Snapshot {snap} are deleting") line of code yield? It doesn't appear in your post.

Going back to my earlier comment, the error you've shown suggests that you are passing "snap-0a8dc05d85036e5fd snap-03e488d013824c092 ..." (with multiple snapshot IDs) to the delete_snapshot call.

yes, 3089 snapshots need to be deleted

Right, but you can't send them all in one API call. Check the value of snapshot_string. Any chance that it is, despite its name, a list containing as the first element a string with multiple snapshot IDs ending in "snap-03e488d013824c092 snap-05e6f9163bc26a4b4". You presumably meant for snapshot_string to be a list of individual IDs, so your earlier join/map/split code is suspect.

I was just thinking the same thing. After the map statement, print output shows '['Snapshot Id',
'snap-0f51c7d3288247f6b',
'snap-010b8a368170ce1b0',
'snap-0bfb10ecdff6c1261',snap-03e488d013824c092',
'snap-05e6f9163bc26a4b4']

I updated my index range to [1:3089]. New error is An error occurred (InvalidSnapshot.InUse) when calling the DeleteSnapshot operation: The snapshot snap-0f51c7d3288247f6b is currently in use by ami-0ed4f9c3d4cd45ac2 so it appears I'm on the right track now
